# World with fire/water/air/earth/shadow/light users; girl on a fire-owned submarine attacked by shadow rebels

Tags: story-identification, books

It's a world that includes fire, water, air, earth, shadow and light users. This world has at least one archipelago with a king, that's died in the previous squashing of rebellion, his descendant lives known only to few. At the beginning of the series a girl is on a fire-owned submarine vessel that gets attacked by Shadow rebels. The Shadow rebels have at least one base in the archipelago and train people there. I'm not totally sure, but I believe there's also an island that has a lot to do with trade. Also, the fire... clergy, I guess? Has absorbed the light part, so basically there are only 5 separate elements remaining.

Some info I'm not quite 100% sure about, but I think the king of the archipelago might also be called **The** or a Pharao

Unfortunately this is pretty much all I remember.

Comment: Do you remember when you read it?

Comment: It was YEARS ago.

Comment: I know the books you're talking about. They're fairly recent - I'd say about ten years old; and it was a trilogy. I vaguely remember that the blurb said that the author was pretty young, too. I'm not sure that that helps at all, though.

Comment: Only helps if you remember the author's or series' name I'm afraid... =/

Comment: @Icdan - I remembered that I had my copy listed on Amazon in the way back when. Five minutes of wandering through years-old listings later..... ;)

Comment: Wny the VTC as too broad by someone ?  Question is clear that name of series is requested and has reasonable details provided.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ah-ha!

It's the [Aquasilva](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anselm_Audley) trilogy, by Anselm Audley:

From the Wikipedia entry:

> Heresy (2001) is set within the stormy waterworld of Aquasilva. Aquasilva is controlled by the Domain, a religious power dedicated to the element fire. The Domain, however, is confronted by many forces of change. One of these unknowing change agents is Cathan, son of the count from Lepidor. Upon discovering iron on their territory, Cathan leaves his home to inform his father of this important find. During his journey Cathan stumbles upon a plot to unleash a new age of fundamentalism. New friends and new powers enable Cathan to confront this extremism.

Comment: It does seem to be it yes. Wow, I've remembered so many things wrongly. Thank you very much! And as by magic I now remember pretty much everything leading up to him being pulled to the Shadow base... AGAIN, thank you!

Comment: You remembered enough that I knew exactly what series you were talking about!