# Trying to find a book's name about a world where only fire magic was legal

Tags: story-identification, magic

It's a book where the only legal magic is fire magic (all the others are illegal) and the protagonist can use water magic, I read it when I was young and can't remember the book's name. Can anyone identify what book I'm talking about?

At some point, in a boat, he makes water magic (which was like the worst kind of sin). I'm sorry I cant remember anything else. If I have to guess a year, it was between 1996 and 2000.

Lastly, but more important, thanks to all of you for taking the time and effort to answer.

Comment: Can you recall any other details about this book? Right now there are only one or two details to go on, which might not be enough. Also, when did you read it (when you were young, but which year, generally speaking)?

Comment: [Sandmagic](http://www.fantasy-magazine.com/new/new-fiction/sandmagic/) by Orson Scott Card?

Comment: I vaguely remember reading something like that. (I may still have the book.) Does the protagonist have to travel to the capital because deposits of valuable minerals were found on his land?

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/43706/world-with-fire-water-air-earth-shadow-light-users-girl-on-a-fire-owned-submari (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's *[Heresy](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/830585.Heresy)* by Anselm Audley, first book of the *Aquasilva Trilogy*. I had the same question and my friend found it for me.

[image: Heresy Book cover]

> On the storm-wracked ocean world of Aquasilva, the priesthood of the Fire-God Ranthas holds supreme religious power.
>   Cathan, reluctant heir to the clan leadership of Lepidor, has never questioned the teachings of Ranthas’s priests and has little interest in politics, preferring to escape into the more orderly world of oceanography. But when a valuable iron deposit is discovered, Cathan must travel to a clan congress to inform his father – and in doing so discovers just how far the Domain is willing to go to secure absolute control, and how much they have distorted what he thought of as the truth.
>
> Sent to a heretic citadel in the outer reaches of the rebellious Archipelago for training, Cathan learns a very different version of Aquasilva’s history, and makes contact with dissidents from across the world – but all of his skills and influence may not be enough when the Domain turns its eyes towards Lepidor . . .